# Getting the text of a textarea under multiple div tags

Tags: html, flask, python-3.8

I have a Flask program like this that is supposed to have two side by side div tags, one for entering python code, and another one for the output:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/python")
def python():
    v = os.listdir(r"...")
    return render_template("python.html", v=v)


@app.route("/run", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def run():
    the_form = request.form
    x = the_form.get("enter-text")

    if x:
        return render_template("python.html", v=x)
    else:
        return render_template("python.html",)


app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is python.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Python</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Welcome to the WPP!</p>

    <form action="/run" method="post">
    <div>
        <div style="float: left;" name="enter-text">
            <textarea rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea rows="20" cols="40" style="margin-left: 6%;">{{v}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div name="submit">
            <button type="submit">Execute</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <p>{{v}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter `print("Hello World!")`, the URL is changed to /run as expected, but nothing is displayed in the output textarea tag. When I tried printing out `x` in the `run()` function, it gives me `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute must be applied to the `textarea` form element. Otherwise the value will not be in the POST request.

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <textarea name="enter-text" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```